# add dicitonaries type data to dropdown (select form element)

Tags: django, django-models, cx-oracle

i have a code to list all data from database to dropdown

```
def makeDictFactory(cursor):
    columnNames = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
    def createRow(*args):
        return dict(zip(columnNames, args))
    return createRow

def list_all_table(request):
    import cx_Oracle
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('', '', sid='') 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'', password='', dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("select table_name from all_tables")
    c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)
    for rowDict in c:
        context = {
            'obj2':rowDict
        }
    #database_table = c.fetchall()  
    return render(request,'define_segment.html',context)
```

this is the html code

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <select style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">              
             {% for table in obj2 %}
                 <option>{{ table.table_name }}</option>
             {% endfor %}                          
      </select>                    
</div>
```

how to pass the parameter to the obj2 in HTML , i have feeling that my views is wrong and i need help to fix it , thank you

P.S : **I need this `views.py` to work to make a dependent dropdown from this code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i already know the answer , so i must append it on list first , because when im not append it on list , it will show the last row , and why it not show?  because in html i use table.table_name , the right way is to write table only because the table already has all the data in obj2 without the columnName. So table only will do the job

here's what i write

VIEWS.PY

```
def makeDictFactory(cursor):
    columnNames = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
    def createRow(*args):
        return dict(zip(columnNames, args))
    return createRow

def list_all_table(request):
    import cx_Oracle
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('', '', sid='') 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'', password='', dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("select table_name from all_tables")
    c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)
    databasetable = []
    for rowDict in c:
        databasetable.append(rowDict['TABLE_NAME'])

    context = {
        'obj2' :databasetable
    }
    return render(request,'define_segment.html',context)
```

html code

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <select style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">              
             {% for table in obj2 %}
                 <option>{{ table }}</option>
             {% endfor %}                          
      </select>                    
</div>
```

and it works!